# Lambda for DoubleFunction

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming

The following snippet is from
https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/quiz-yourself-functional-interfaces-advanced?source=:em:nw:mt::RC_WWMK190726P00001:NSL400004372

```
DoubleStream ds = DoubleStream.of(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
DoubleFunction<DoubleUnaryOperator> fun = a -> d -> d + a;
System.out.print(ds.map(fun.apply(1.0)).sum());
```

In my learning of lambdas I understand things like
`d -> d+a` or even `(d, a) -> d+a` 
but although knowing the effect of the function, I can't figure out the syntax of the above lambda.
Could someone please explain or give a link to some tutorial?
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a -> d -> d + a;
```

is the same as

```
a -> (d -> d + a);
```

which is a Function that for a double `a` returns a Function that for a double `d` returns the sum of `a` and `d`.

For more details on **partial application of functions**, or **turning multi-argument function into multiple single argument functions**, see [currying](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/currying-functions-in-java-with-examples/).